# Дата публикации Joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Как вывести в запись дату её публикации?
Точнее, с помощью какого кода?

Joomla 1.5.

Т.е. что-то типа:

```
Опубликовано: <?php echo $date_publication; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($record->created)); ?>
```

`$record` - ваша запись, `d.m.Y` - формат `24.01.2012`, за другими смотрим справку к функции [`date`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php).

Comment: Везде выводит одно и то же: 31.12.1969.
Думаю, дело в $record. Т.к. я в Joomla почти не разбираюсь, то прошу пояснить, что Вы имели ввиду под "$record - ваша запись" - т.е. id записи, контент записи, заголовок?..
Если id, то у меня сразу возникает вопрос: как получить id, т.к. нигде, кроме как в url, я его на странице больше не вижу (смотрел код).

Comment: if(CMS == 'Joomla') die('fatal error); XD

Comment: Ваша запись - это объект записи. Обращение к id через оператор метода привело бы к ошибке. Если id есть "только в адресной строке", получить запись можно так:

    $DB = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $DB->setQuery('SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE id='.(int)JRequest::getVar('id'));
    $record = $DB->loadObject() or die('Запись не найдена');
    var_dump($record); // покажет вам, какие вообще есть поля

Comment: @Palmervan, тогда уж так =) Рабочий способ)

    !defined('_JEXEC') or die('<b>Fatal error</b>:  require() [<a href=\'function.require\'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required \''.rand(100, 10000).'.php\' (include_path=\'.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php\') in <b>'.JPATH_BASE.'/index.php</b> on line <b>'.rand(4, 50).'</b><br />');

На джумле покажет ошибку в случайной строке джумловского `index.php`.

Comment: @Sh4dow у меня нет повода не согласится ;)